# Why is my Twitter Page in Arabic?

Tags: twitter

My Twitter page shows up on Google searches in a language I assume is Arabic, and Arabic is the default language when I log in. I have tried to change it back to English in settings, but it changes back whenever I log in. I also have "United Kingdom" listed as my country in account settings, so I don’t see why it is doing this. How could I change it back to English?

Answer (score 1):

Try appending **`?lang=en`** to the end of the URL and bookmark it like that **https://twitter.com?lang=en** - (after you clean cookies).

> To correct your country setting:
>
> **1.** Sign in to your Twitter account - **https://twitter.com/#!/login**
> **2.** Visit your Account settings - **https://twitter.com/settings/account**
> **3.** Select the correct country from the drop-down
> **4.** Click **Save**
>
> **[https://help.twitter.com/help](https://help.twitter.com/en/managing-your-account/how-to-change-country-settings)**